# google web tookkit show Input HTML inside radio button

Tags: gwt

I have build the radio button using the `GWT`, but now i want to associate a drop down for each radio button. let say i have two radio button name Yes and No. if I click on first radio button (Yes) then next line should show the associate drop down. if click on second radio button (No) then first radio button drop down should hide.

How  I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Add ClickHandler or ValueChangeHandler to the radio Buttons.

Noow you can set the correct value to the dropDown below or just make two dropdowns and set one visible and the other invisble.